# Fall with drag - ignoring the gravitational force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, projectile, drag

Say we have a fall while considering air resistance

$$ma=mg-Bv^2.$$

It is a standard differential equation.

But then I was asked what would happen, if we ignore the gravitational force $mg$. Now I am confused, why or when can we ignore the gravitational force? I assume when the object is very very small so that it doesn't matter anymore? But then

$$m\frac{d^2 s}{dt^2}=-B\left(\frac{ds}{dt}\right)^2.$$

What exactly does this say about the situation?

Comment: I am not sure what the person asking you the question meant by "what would happen". Do they mean what would the motion be if gravity was suddenly 'switched off'; or do they mean what would be the change in the equation describing the motion?

Comment: A circumstance where the gravitational force becomes irrelevant, might be when the aerodynamic drag is massively higher than the weight... e.g. soon after a high-velocity bullet leaves the barrel of a gun, fired vertically; or a meteorite enters the earth's atmosphere at transonic speeds

Comment: It's not clear exact situation what is asked. If gravity would be switched off in the process of free fall, then obviously body will stop at some point due to air resistance (or it would hit the surface due to inertia if drag force not big enough to stop the body at $h=0$). If gravity is switched-off right before body is released for falling - it would simply stay at the same height $h=h_0=\text{const}$ at rest. Depends...

Comment: Comment about terminology: A fall with air resistance is by definition not a free fall.

Comment: *I assume when the object is very very small so that it doesn't matter anymore?*  This is wrong.  Gravity affects the object regardless of it's size.  Aerodynamic drag does depend on size - basically the bigger it's cross section the more drag.

Comment: Regarding very very small objects, you may be thinking of things like Brownian motion or a colloidal suspension. Very small insoluble particles can remain suspended in a fluid indefinitely and won't precipitate to the bottom, because the tiny gravitational force acting on each particle is vastly outweighed by other interaction forces between particles. It's not the same thing as drag, but it's a similar situation in which gravity always acts, but can be negligible in the face of stronger forces.

Answer (score 10):

This is a simplification when **drag is much larger than the gravitational force**. In order for this to work the drag must be at least order of magnitude larger. When initial velocity is (*close to*) zero, the simplification obviously does not work as it predicts the object to remain at rest.

The free-fall example is little bit difficult to imagine. Much better example would be a moving car with no force from the motor, assuming the car moves on a horizontal surface (road).

---

If the equation of motion is given as:

$$m \frac{d^2}{dt^2} x(t) = -k \cdot v(t)^2$$

it can be written as

$$m \frac{d}{dt} v(t) = -k \cdot v(t)^2$$

which equals to

$$\int \frac{dv(t)}{v(t)^2} = -\int \frac{k}{m} dt$$

This finally leads to

$$\frac{1}{v(t)} = \kappa t + C_1$$

where $\kappa = \frac{k}{m}$, $C_1 = \frac{1}{v_0}$, and $v_0$ is the initial velocity.

The equation for velocity is

$$\boxed{v(t) = \frac{v_0}{1 + \kappa v_0 t}}$$

From this it is trivial to find the equation for position:

$$\boxed{x(t) = \frac{1}{\kappa} \ln(1 + \kappa v_0 t)}$$

Note that the velocity approaches zero with time, i.e. the drag is slowing the object.

Comment: Hi question on initial velocity. What shall we do if it’s 0?

Comment: The equations I derived do not put any constraints to initial velocity. For $v_0 = 0$ the object remains at rest, i.e. $x(t) = 0$ and $v(t) = 0$.

Comment: Which means the object would float in air at whatever height?

Comment: That would be reasonable to assume, but the thing is that this simplification works only while drag is much higher than the gravitational force, I'd say at least order of magnitude higher. When velocity is sufficiently small, you can no longer neglect gravitational force.

Comment: I find the phrasing "the drag is stopping the object" a bit misleading since the object will travel arbitrarily far given enough time. Maybe "slowing" would be better?

Comment: @schtandard You are right, “slowing” is better than “stopping”, I changed it, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

@MarkoGulin has fully addressed the mathematical aspect of the problem. I thus add a remark regarding the physical situations where the equation in question can be relevant:

- Drag force is ubiquitous when we talk about movement of macroscopic objects in a gas or liquid. It is not hard to think of examples that do not involve free fall: e.g.,
- - a boat or a submarine that has turned off its engines,
- - a glider aircraft,
- - an immobile helicopter or a baloon carried by a gust of wind,
- - a meteorite or a satellite entering the Earth's atmosphere, etc.
- Projectile motion: here we are dealing with a bit more complicated situation, since the drag force is proportional to the square of the full velocity:
  $$m\dot{\mathbf{v}}=m\mathbf{g}-B\frac{\mathbf{v}}{|\mathbf{v}|}\mathbf{v}^2.$$
  However, when the horizontal velocity is very big, we can approximate it by
  $$m\dot{v}_x=-Bv_x^2.
  $$